# Restricted Messaging

Tags: messages

My daughter has an iphone and I would like to restrict when and who she can text with.  I'm aware that you can turn off the messaging completely but that's not wanted.  Is there a way to only allow texting to and from specific numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't restrict **Messages** by person/number.  You can only turn **Messages** *off* or *on*.  [This site](http://www.bewebsmart.com/ipod-ipad-iphone/how-to-restrict-imessage/) can show you how to do that while using Restrictions to prevent your daughter from making changes.

There are some 3rd-party applications that might be able to do what you want.  Search the App Store for messaging apps that have that feature.